# "File mask" of "Find in Path" command in Pycharm 2019.3.1 (community edition) does not contain *.py option

Tags: python, search, path, mask

I will like to use the "Find in Path" -CNTL-SHIFT -F  command to search for words in .xml and .py files but when the File in Path screen comes up, the file mask only contains 3 extensions - *.xml, *.css and *.html

How do I include *.py in the File mask so that I can be able to search inside python files in my project as well. Thank you

[screenshot of File in path command showing only *.xml,*.css and *.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEKWv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Locate your find.xml file at

```
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/options/find.xml
```

for linux path -

```
file:///home/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/options/find.xml
```

Replace file content with below code-:

```
<application>
  <component name="FindSettings">
    <option name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
    <option name="customScope" value="All Places" />
    <option name="defaultScopeName" value="All Places" />
    <option name="showResultsInSeparateView" value="true" />
    <option name="wholeWordsOnly" value="true" />
    <option name="CASE_SENSITIVE_SEARCH" value="true" />
    <option name="WHOLE_WORDS_ONLY" value="true" />
    <option name="SHOW_RESULTS_IN_SEPARATE_VIEW" value="true" />
    <option name="SEARCH_SCOPE" value="All Places" />
    <mask>*.css</mask>
    <mask>*.xml</mask>
    <mask>*.html</mask>
    <mask>*.js,*.html</mask>
    <mask>*.js</mask>
    <mask>*.py</mask>
  </component>
</application>
```

You also have to restart Pycharm for the changes to take effect.